# MongoDB timeseries: find documents by the "metaField"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, time-series

I have defined the following TS collection:

```
db.createCollection(
    "values",
    {
       timeseries: {
          timeField: "timestamp",
          metaField: "meta",
          granularity: "minutes"
       }
    }
)
```

my `meta` value is a comprised of two fields. For example, `{"country": "US", "customer": "Some Bank"}`

After inserting a few documents, I'm trying:

```
db.getCollection('values').find({"meta": {"country": "US", "customer": "Some Bank"}})
```

But no documents is retrieved. Why?

Comment: try: 
db.getCollection('values').find({"meta.country": "US", "meta.customer": "Some Bank"})